# Relations between interval and semitones

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, music

Output this table:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -2* | -1* | - | 0 | - | 1 | 2 |
| -1* | 0 | 1 | - | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | - | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | - | 5 | - | 6 | 7 |
| 5 | 6 | - | 7 | - | 8 | 9 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | - | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | - | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 10 | 11 | - | 12 | - | 13 | 14 |

- You can output one string with two types of split, 1D string array with one type of split, or 2D string array
- If your language support mixed type then you can fill numbers in number cells(but not `-1*` and `-2*`)
- If your number type has one value `-` then you can use it in `-` cells. Otherwise they should be text `-`.
- This table comes from [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25851/76323) but I removed 1st row and 1st column
- Shortest code wins

Comment: Why can't the asterisked negative numbers be represented with a numeric type? Looking at the linked Sandbox post you got the table from, it looks like the asterisks just refer to a footnote...

Comment: @UnrelatedString Because `-1*` isn't `-1`

Comment: @l4m2: what Unrelated String is saying is that the \*s are just pointing to the footnote _"\* Negative distance doesn't exist but it can be added 12 until non-negative"_ - they aren't actually part of the table.

Comment: "split" -> "delimiter"? Also, I'm not entirely sure what the 3rd bullet point means... does it mean that you can use NaN or null?

Comment: What's the use of the asterisk in `-2*`; the original footnote is missing.

Comment: @Kaz No document would write `-2` and `-1` there...

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 90 bytes

Returns a single string, using commas and line feeds as delimiters.

```javascript
f=(n=7)=>~n--?[..."0024200"].map(j=>4-(n&2)&j?'-':v+["**"[++v+1]],v=34-n*7>>2)+`
`+f(n):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCsIgFADQ9z7Dh@nVFDNhMNB9iAiTNSNZ19HCx37dzimppXP9vI6vxPrYes@OoRvB@R9KOQelFNHaWKM1ieqdDlact5LhYGAoM5V0aiIQzkkQoolbjNfm7lYiH703IJbLIjJDmCjta8Wz7pva65NlBtD/)

Or **78 bytes** without the asterisks:

```javascript
f=(n=7)=>~n--?[..."0024200"].map(j=>4-(n&2)&j?'-':v++,v=34-n*7>>2)+`
`+f(n):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCsIwEADAu8/oodk1bggxUChs@hARGmojhropVnL063EmxxqP5fPavyTlsbaWGIQH5PAToulmjOmsdd5Z293NO@6QOXgC6R32eVKkxqr1pfLVk5yHEBzq@TTrBIKjUm0pcpRtNVt5QgLE9gc)

#### How?

We iterate from \$n=6\$ to \$n=-1\$. The starting value of each row can be obtained with:

$$v_n=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{4}(34-7n)\right\rfloor$$

There are 2 distinct row patterns:

$$\begin{cases}[v_n,v_n+1,\varnothing,v_n+2,\varnothing,v_n+3,v_n+4]&n\in\{-1,2,3,6\}\\
[v_n,v_n+1,v_n+2,\varnothing,v_n+3,v_n+4,v_n+5]&n\in\{0,1,4,5\}\end{cases}$$

We can just test the penultimate bit of \$n\$ to distinguish them. We generate \$2\$ if it's set or \$4\$ otherwise and do a bitwise AND with the digit from the lookup string `"0024200"` according to its position.

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 96 bytes

```perl6
{map ->\i,\j {{j-3,j-2,$_&&j-1,!$_&&j-1,$_&&j,j+$_,j+1+$_}((153+>i)%%2)},<1 2 4 6 8 9 11 13>.kv}
```

Returns the output as a 2D list with `False` for the blanks.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1uplmb7vzo3sUBB1y4mUycmS6G6OkvXWCdL10hHJV5NLUvXUEcRxgDTOlnaKvFAwhBI1WpoGJoaa9tlaqqqGmnW6tgYKhgpmCiYKVgoWCoYGioYGtvpZZfV/i9OrFRIs/4PAA)

Comment: How fo `False` == `-`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>47</s> <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
Ｅ⁸Ｅ⁺Σ…68ι⊕Ｅ⁷Σ…432234λ⎇﹪λ⁴⁺⊖⊖÷λ⁴…*‹λ⁸-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BCoMwEER/JeS0lnhRaYUe9SIoCO0PhLhgYE0kUcGvT409VLqXXWZm36hROmUlhdA7bRbo5AylYHH1tHp4rRNUuyKsRjsDv5dcMJ0kgjVGOZzQLDicTw/B/rJFnmV5ceQpiSPYG52RbofODitZIMGKQz1ravzRrndjllpvesBvOlIuDbcD3qL30SxPk6c8dj1DCOlGHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal array, i.e. each element on its own line and each row double-spaced from the previous. Explanation:

```
 ⁸                                      Literal integer `8`
Ｅ                                       Map over implicit range
           ⁷                            Literal integer `7`
          Ｅ                             Map over implicit range
              432234                    Literal string `432234`
             …                          Truncated to length
                    λ                   Current column
            Σ                           Digital sum
         ⊕                              Vectorised increment
   ⁺                                    Vectorised add
      68                                Literal string `68`
     …                                  Extended to length
        ι                               Current row
    Σ                                   Digital sum
  Ｅ                                     Map over list
                       λ                Inner value
                      ﹪                 Modulo
                        ⁴               Literal integer `4`
                     ⎇                  If divisible then
                                    -   Literal string `-` otherwise
                             λ          Current value
                            ÷           Integer divided by
                              ⁴         Literal integer `4`
                           ⊖            Incremented
                          ⊖             Incremented
                         ⁺              Concatenated with
                                *       Literal string `*`
                               …        Truncated to length
                                  λ     Current value
                                 ‹      Is less than
                                   ⁸    Literal integer `8`
```

The program works by generating the following table, where the headers are generated from a list of differences:

| + | 1 | 5 | 8 | 10 | 12 | 15 | 19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | 8 | 10 | 12 | 15 | 19 |
| 6 | 7 | 11 | 14 | 16 | 18 | 21 | 25 |
| 14 | 15 | 19 | 22 | 24 | 26 | 29 | 33 |
| 20 | 21 | 25 | 28 | 30 | 32 | 35 | 39 |
| 28 | 29 | 33 | 36 | 38 | 40 | 43 | 47 |
| 34 | 35 | 39 | 42 | 44 | 46 | 49 | 53 |
| 42 | 43 | 47 | 50 | 52 | 54 | 57 | 61 |
| 48 | 49 | 53 | 56 | 58 | 60 | 63 | 67 |

Multiples of `4` are replaced with `-` while the remaining numbers are integer divided by `4` and then decremented twice, appending a `*` if this reduces them below zero.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 47 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
6L3-D>3FDÌ}D>DÌDÌ)εƵqbNèi¨Ƶ;S£ë3ô}'-.ý˜εD0‹i'*«
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##JY0xCsJAEEWvsl1QfmQmu0kUIVWwEhtLsTBgkUrEOuABPIKdTSCtW1jYZCGNkEN4kTgbYXd4700xp8uhKI/DkKx1mGd6lbtblWcy5U1629lzsXF12dadXW7bh2u0e1ZBOHPvz723OX2vrzKYts0w7BgRCFq@QQwVCRqRGAlSKDMCCc6xgPKNBEmECcpH8iSDwRHU2IXJG2uwgfqv2N8Q5RicSBx35JV84HT/Aw)

**Explanation:**

```python
6L             # Push list [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  3-           # Decrease each by 3: [-2,-1,0,1,2,3]
D>             # Duplicate it, and increase each by 1
3F  }          # Loop 3 times:
  DÌ           #  Duplicate the top list, and increase each by 2
D>DÌDÌ         # Three more duplicates with +1, +2, and +2 respectively again
)              # Wrap all lists on the stack into a list
 ε             # Map over each inner list:
  Ƶq           #  Push compressed integer 153
    b          #  Convert it to binary: 10011001
     Nè        #  Index the current map-index into it
       i       #  If this is 1:
        ¨      #   Remove the last item of the list
         Ƶ;    #   Push compressed integer 212
           S   #   Convert it to a list: [2,1,2]
            £  #   Split the list into parts of that size: [[a,b],[c],[d,e]]
       ë       #  Else:
        3ô     #   Split the list into triplets: [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]
       }       #  After the if-else:
        '-.ý  '#  Intersperse the list of sub-lists with "-" delimiter
            ˜  #  And flatten it to a single list again
  ε            #  Map over each inner value:
   D           #   Duplicate the current value
    0‹i        #   Pop the copy, and if it's a negative integer:
       '*«    '#    Append a "*"
               # (after which the matrix is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ƶq` is `153` and `Ƶ;` is `212`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>222</s> 216 bytes

```python
r=[];z=(0,3,4,7);m=-1
for i in range(8):
	r.append([]);s=i*2-(i+1)//4
	for q in range(7):d=q-3-int(q>3)+int(q<2 and i in z);r[m]+=[s+d];r[m][m]="-"if(q in(2,4)and i in z)or q==3 and i in(1,2,5,6)else r[m][m]
print(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BDoIwFETX9hQNq35pRSiKoX4vQliQANpESils5PJo0ajJLGYx7419TLfeyGVxWJRqRrbnkqc8A9WhiEnbO6qpNtRV5tqwE@Rk43aVtY2pWVGCGlFvE8F0GEMUpWTjgeEHZJDXOAgptJnYcJEQruWc0MrUb/MMyhVdGWIxhnW59lcwEIFumVexhKfwN/cPiPJrYDFP@IEfobmPDf3wxDr/5GBZng)

Comment: Welcome to code golf! Is your code producing the dashes in the right place? In particular, `q==3 and z in(1,2,5,6)` looks strange because `q==3` seems to cause `z==2`.

Comment: Yes you are right! I had it working perfect, but two of my variable-name substitutions pointed to d! I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 76 bytes

```python
n=0
for r in b"(($"*2:n+=-4|r;print([r%c*'-'or(n:=n+1)for c in b""])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P8/WgCstv0ihSCEzTyFJSVRDQ0VJy8gqT9tW16SmyLqgKDOvRCO6SDVZS11XPb9II8/KNk/bUBOkJRmihZGRlZmVkVEpVvP/fwA)

This prints each row as its own list. The two bytestrings contain unprintable characters -- here's the code with their ASCII values shown:

```python
n=0
for r in[21,40,40,36]*2:n+=-4|r;print([r%c*'-'or(n:=n+1)for c in[1,1,5,3,5,1,1]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P8/WgCstv0ihSCEzL9rIUMfEAISMzWK1jKzytG11TWqKrAuKMvNKNKKLVJO11HXV84s08qxs87QNNUH6kkH6DHUMdUx1jIEYyIqN1fz/HwA)

The `r`'s in `[21,40,40,36]*2` correspond to the 8 rows, and the `c`'s in `[1,1,5,3,5,1,1]` to the 7 columns. They are chosen to make a "modulo table" producing the positions of the dashes, with a dash where `r%c==1` and `r%c==0` elsewhere.

```python
           c
     1 1 5 3 5 1 1 
r  %--------------
21 | 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
40 | 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
40 | 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
36 | 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
21 | 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
40 | 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
40 | 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
36 | 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Each non-dash position is filled with the number `n`, which is first incremented. Changes to `n` persist between rows, so before the start of each row we decrease `n` from the end of the previous row by substracting either 3 or 4, noting that it will increment by 1 before the first value is produced.

These deltas are encoded per-row by the `r`'s as `-4|r`, which produces `[-4,-3,-3,-3,-4,-3,-3,-3]`. Because this pattern repeats in 2 blocks of 4 for the 8 rows, as did the dash pattern, we write the `r`'s list as a four-entry list repeated twice, saving bytes.

Here are all the properties we needed the hardcoded `r`'s and `c`'s to satisfy:

```python
-4|21 == -3
-4|40 == -4
-4|36 == -4

 21%5 == 36%5 == 1
 40%3 == 1
 21%1 == 40%1 == 36%1 == 40%5 == 21%3 == 36%3 == 0
```

I found these with a brute-force search, and many other options were possible.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 145 bytes

Port of [@xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263041/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BC4JAEIXv/opBCHZxFTetg7ZBP6CTdIoOm61i6WrjEoT5223NWzAD7328eUyfy1pO7fWucgNHWWkYHICbKqCxhkgs@wQOiPJ9zgxWurzQBE66MiBgmF4SQYswLVokuPMz9SRrzuJwnmhLPe@f0EF7Avz4g2ln20ytyRzhjLMNi@xaRYNGdiQX@6oguMqFCH9XPNWBaZcnRlX3yvVdG30shLjMpXScAEZnnL4)

```scala
var n=0;for(r<-Seq(21,40,40,36)++Seq(21,40,40,36)){n+= -4|r;println(Seq(1,1,5,3,5,1,1).map(c=>if(r%c==0){n+=1;n.toString}else"-").mkString(","))}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDBSsQwFLz3K4aCkNBt2dXVw7IVvOtJPImHGNMlbpouSRRk7bfXlyZUD0KSx0xm3pvES2HENA2v70oGPAhtcS6AN9WhJ8CEO/gd7pwTX8@PwWl7eOE7PFkd0M5K4FM4WELrjAycJ3ivfWCXmxW267Svbjiq6l9@ccrFSQJa13Q9nxHyYtZ1gwNz2Nc0h@cMoARVi3qLb7jMzEmU/zAxqvRNL044Q6K9zQJAd7HTRSQp/2@zpeHmL9GEIX3BQo5QxiuUdZmpMdcTyYKxLM1v@mMysnKFkqfnRulYjMU0/QA)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var n = 0
    val rs = List(21, 40, 40, 36) ++ List(21, 40, 40, 36)
    val cs = List(1, 1, 5, 3, 5, 1, 1)

    for (r <- rs) {
      n += -4 | r
      val result = cs.map { c =>
        if (r % c == 0) {
          n += 1
          n.toString
        } else "-"
      }
      println(result.mkString(", "))
    }
  }
}
```